# Try/Except doesnt work with tflearn. Please

Tags: tensorflow, model, nlp, chatbot, tflearn

I am a noob and i need help. If I try this simple try/except statement and if I havn't a pretrained model to load, I always get an error.
But if I have already a model to load it works. It does also work when I remove the try/except and train my model every time I run my programm.
Thanks.

```
try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=300, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eric/PycharmProjects/ai_chatbot/nlp.py", line 82, in <module>
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=300, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 206, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 344, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 826, in _train
    tflearn.is_training(True, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 95, in is_training
    tf.get_collection('is_training_ops')[0].eval(session=session)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 921, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5512, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 968, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1114, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

PS: I use anaconda with a venv and tflearn for my model

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how tflearn works but I think your error comes from this line: `model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=300, batch_size=8, show_metric=Tr` which is outside `try:` block.